# i cant access methods form a class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, module

i  can't  access a method form a class from paddel.js to use it inside input.js file .
but i can access it's properties

```
//inputs.js

import Paddle from './paddel.js'

export default class InputHandler{
    constructor(paddle){
        document.addEventListener('keydown' , (event)=>{
           // console.log(event.keyCode)
           switch(event.keyCode){
               case 37 :  console.log(Paddle.moveLeft)                 
           }
        })
    }
}


//paddel.js file

 export default  class Paddle{
    constructor(){
        this.width=150;
     }

    moveLeft(){
        console.log("go left")
    }
}
```

Comment: When writing like that I believe you need to do `Paddle.default.moveLeft`

Comment: A method is meant to be accessed from an instance of the class. Is there a reason you're trying to get it from the class definition itself?

Comment: "*but i can access its properties*" - uh, no, you can't access `.width` either. If you think you can, please show us the code you are using to do that.

Comment: Please don't deface your posts. Even a "silly" question might be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `paddle` then using `Paddle`. `paddle` in your case is an instance of `Paddle`, so you need to use the instance and call the method, don't use the class itself.

```
  export default class InputHandler{
     constructor(paddle){
         document.addEventListener('keydown' , (event)=>{
               // console.log(event.keyCode)
               switch(event.keyCode){
                   case 37 :  console.log(paddle.moveLeft())                 
               }
            })
        }
    }

 export default  class Paddle{
    constructor(){
        this.width=150;
     }

    moveLeft(){
        console.log("go left")
    }
}
const test = new InputHandler(new Paddle());
```

Also call the method like this `moveLeft()`.

Comment: +1. One might even drop the `import Paddle from './paddel.js'` if the `Paddel` class is not used statically anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `Paddle.moveLeft()` you are trying to call a *static* method on that class. See the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

The way you set up the Paddle class, you would need to first create an instance of the Paddle class, eg:

```
const paddle = new Paddle()
```

and then call the method on the instance of that class

```
paddle.moveLeft()
```

Answer (score 0):

> export default class InputHandler{
>       constructor(paddle){

When adding paddle to the constructor - be mindful that an InputHandler will need to be instantiated with a paddle object:

```
const ih = new InputHandler(new Paddle());
```

In which case, you don't need to import the Paddle class in your inputHandler class.